# desire2learn email functionality API

Tags: desire2learn

I am looking the email functionality api for desire2learn , i have read all the api documentation which i was not able to find those . The use case from web ui is Click Course -> classlist -> display list of users - > you can select the users and then click Email icon on the bottom , this will open a windows for entering email text .

i am planning to integrate this feature by calling rest api .

Please help to find api in the documentation or confirm those apis are not available?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently now APIs directly for sending or dealing with email in Desire2Learn. One approach would be to use the User and Profile apis to access addresses and then use standard smtp relays to send email.